# How can I speed up initial TypeScript compile times

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a fairly big TypeScript project (200+ files) and it takes some time (10s+) to boot up when I run it in watch mode (`tsc --watch`). However once its going it is pretty fast to do a full typecheck TypeScript.

How can I speed up the initial boot of `tsc --watch`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TypeScript 3.4 rc got the `--incremental` compiler option ([blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4-rc/)).

When it is enabled TypeScript will generate a `.tsbuildinfo` file if there isn't one already (so you still play the 10s+ penalty once). But if it exists, a cold `tsc --watch` run will be super fast (no longer 10s delay).

## How to enable incremental builds

Either with command line flag `--incremental` or in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "incremental": true
    }
}
```

Comment: I did `--incremental` from the command line, and it threw `error TS5074: Option '--incremental' can only be specified using tsconfig, emitting to single file or when option '--tsBuildInfoFile' is specified. Found 1 error.`

Comment: `--incremental` flag will help but it's still slower than `tsc --watch` incremental compilations. There is an issue in GitHub about that with more details https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46420